# How to add project with google/cloud-firestore on azure deployment

Tags: php, azure, google-cloud-firestore, azure-web-app-service, grpc

I am trying to deploy a github project with google/cloud-firestore as one of the depenecies. This requires grpc.so to be installed and enabled in the php extension.

I have tried following the Azure wiki advise (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-php?pivots=platform-linux#customize-php_ini_system-directives) to add it as a custom extension including it on the github (using LFS) + adding the setting.ini file (extension=/home/site/wwwroot/bin/grpc.so) however when I try and deploy it it always errors with

```
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

  Problem 1
    - google/cloud-firestore is locked to version v1.37.6 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - google/cloud-firestore v1.37.6 requires ext-grpc * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's grpc extension.
```